# using android facebook sdk to post videos

Tags: android, facebook

I am trying to use android facebook sdk to post videos. through a long time. the onComplete method have been actived . but it couldn't show in Facebook. I also add the permission `{user_videos,publish_stream,read_stream etc..}`

```
public void uploadVideo(String dataPath,String VideoDescription)
{
    InputStream in = null ;
    byte[] data ;
    Bundle param ;

    try{
        in = new FileInputStream(dataPath);
        Log.e(tag, "start reading..");
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
          Log.e(tag, "coudlnt find.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    data = readBytes(in);
    param = new Bundle();

    param.putString("name", "adfasdfasdf");
    param.putString("message", "sdfsdf");
    param.putString("filename", "MOV008.mp4");
    param.putString("description", VideoDescription);
    param.putByteArray("video", data);
    Log.e(tag, "upload");
    Utility.mAsyncRunner.request("me/videos", param,"POST",new fbRequestListener(),null);
}
```